# How to set up a unique group of IDs using auto-increment and SQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

I am exporting data from a .csv file. The file contains a sports player attributes e.g catching, throwing, jumping. Each sports player can have more than one attribute so i need to set up a unique ID for each of the attributes.
I want to set it up so that catching is given the unique number 1, throwing 2 and so on.
I thought about using some form of auto increment but i just cant work it out.

This is what i have:
          **ID(No)    /    Skill(Action)**
               1         Catching
               2         Scoring
               3         Throwing
               4         Jumping
               5         Catching
               6         Jumping
               7         Running

But what i would like is:

```
           **ID       Skill**
            1        Catching
            2        Scoring
            3        Throwing
            1        Catching
            3        Throwing
            etc
```

I am using phpMyAdmin to produce this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? mysql, postgressql....

Comment: Then you have [autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). Mysql isn't my flavor of choice, but others will help you. Can you edit your question and add a mysql tag?

Comment: Btw, while rereading your question, I'm not sure of what you want to do. It would help if you add a row of data that you want to import and show what result you want. Also, are you using some kind of script when importing the data (like php)?

Comment: So you have one table for attributes, one table for players, and one table that links players with their respective attributes.

Comment: Ok. I suggest that you do something like `CREATE TABLE attributes(id integer, name varchar(20)`, and populate that with the list of known properties, another table with all the players, an a third with the playerid, attributeid and value.